# How do I use an IF statement in PHP to decide if I should show an image or not?

Tags: php, html, image

I'm setting up a weather page using the *wunderground.com API*. Anyway, I want to do the following:

Of the variable `$weather` is equal to `Clear`, I want to display an image.

I've tried this:

```
if ($weather=="Clear") echo <img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>
```

What do I need to do instead?

Comment: No need to downvote this. It is genuine question. Yes it lack some basic ideas and research but, is not DOWNVOTE Worthy. +1 from me

Comment: What is happening to SO Community? No one is putting any effort while answering the answer. Answers are not in the form of "Try this..." those are comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($weather=="Clear") echo '<img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>';
```

Comment: Please put some effort while answering the answer. Why will this solution work, what mistake OP did. Mentioning this will make your answer better and useful.

Answer (score 2):

The code you tried will render ***ERROR***. You need to place the HTML text and any string within quotes, before you `echo`  them.

```
if ($weather=="Clear") echo '<img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>'
```

Remaining, there is nothing else to improve :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I am sorry. I dont follow you

Comment: nvm. There was a -1 on yours and now its gone. IT used to be `+1/-1`, not its `+1/0`

Comment: @ColeJohnson, Oh, somebody might not have liked my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($weather==="Clear") 
  echo "<img src=\"http://example.org/clear.gif\" alt=\"Clear\"/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>';
```

OR

```
 echo "<img src='http://example.org/clear.gif' alt='Clear' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($weather=="Clear")  echo "<img src=\"http://example.org/clear.gif\" alt=\"Clear\"/>";
```

OR

```
if ($weather==="Clear") echo '<img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>';
```

OR

```
if ($weather==="Clear") echo <<<ABC
<img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>
ABC;
```

andsoon.

Answer (score 0):

For conditionally rendering html, I often just use the php tags...

```
if($weather === "Clear") {?>
  <img src="http://example.org/clear.gif" alt="Clear"/>
<?php}
```